# Passing data from attribute values into tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, vis.js, tipped

I'm trying to create a timeline containing items which have certain attributes which then need to be displayed inside a tooltip when hovering over the corresponding item. I have got the timeline to work (I used [vis.js](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/)), but can't get the attribute values to display (dynamically) in the tooltips for each item. I have been trying to use tipped.js, the documentation for this can be found [here](http://www.tippedjs.com/documentation). Judging by the documentation it should certainly be possible, but my knowledge of jQuery/Javascript is not extensive enough to do it... Could someone help with this?

The HTML I have now can be viewed below. I have included a separate script tag at the bottom of the body for the tooltip code. Right now all the tooltips display the text defined in this code. The attributes I want to be displayed for each tooltip are content, start, end, object, subject (as defined in the datasat for the timeline), preferably in the form of a table.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/vis.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/tipped.js"></script>
<link href="include/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="include/vis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="include/tipped.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
 <div id="menu">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div id="container">

 <div id="tabmenu">
     &nbsp;
    </div>
    
    <div id="timeline-block">
     <h2>Timeline</h2>
        <div id="timeline">
                <div class="menu">
                    <input type="button" id="zoomIn" value="Zoom in"/>
                    <input type="button" id="zoomOut" value="Zoom out"/>
                    <input type="button" id="moveLeft" value="Move right"/>
                    <input type="button" id="moveRight" value="Move left"/>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // DOM element where the Timeline will be attached
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline');

  // Create a DataSet (allows two way data-binding)
  var items = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, content: 'Versie 1.0', start: '2015-01-01', end: '2016-01-01', subject: 'Name1', object: 'Car'},
 {id: 2, content: 'Versie 2.0', start: '2016-01-01', end: '2016-05-18', className: 'suspended', subject: 'Name2', object: 'Car'},
 {id: 3, content: 'Versie 3.0', start: '2016-05-18', end: '2016-12-29', className: 'current', subject: 'Name3', object: 'Car'},
  ]);

  // Configuration for the Timeline
  var options = {
   width: '100%',
   rtl: true,
   showCurrentTime: true,
   stack: false,
   zoomMax: 150000000000,
   zoomMin: 200,
   dataAttributes: 'all'
   };

  // Create a Timeline
  var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
 
  
  /**NAVIGATION BUTTONS
     * Move the timeline a given percentage to left or right
     * @param {Number} percentage   For example 0.1 (left) or -0.1 (right)
     */
    function move (percentage) {
        var range = timeline.getWindow();
        var interval = range.end - range.start;
        timeline.setWindow({
            start: range.start.valueOf() - interval * percentage,
            end:   range.end.valueOf()   - interval * percentage
        });
    }
    /**
     * Zoom the timeline a given percentage in or out
     * @param {Number} percentage   For example 0.1 (zoom out) or -0.1 (zoom in)
     */
    function zoom (percentage) {
        var range = timeline.getWindow();
        var interval = range.end - range.start;
        timeline.setWindow({
            start: range.start.valueOf() - interval * percentage,
            end:   range.end.valueOf()   + interval * percentage
        });
    }
    // attach events to the navigation buttons
    document.getElementById('zoomIn').onclick    = function () { zoom(-0.2); };
    document.getElementById('zoomOut').onclick   = function () { zoom( 0.2); };
    document.getElementById('moveLeft').onclick  = function () { move( 0.2); };
    document.getElementById('moveRight').onclick = function () { move(-0.2); };
 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   
    Tipped.create('.vis-item', 'Some tooltip text');
 
  });
</script>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is ".vis-item" ?

Comment: .vis-item is the timeline element generated by creating a new object in the dataSet.  You can find a live example here: http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/basicUsage.html

Comment: Can you try "$(window).load" instead of "$(document).ready" ?

Comment: As it is it all works fine, the tooltip is displayed. I just need the tooltip content to be generated differently :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`A function can be used as content for the tooltip. It should return the content to be pushed into the tooltip. The first argument within the function refers to the element the tooltip was created for`*:

http://www.tippedjs.com/documentation#usage_functions

```
   Tipped.create('.vis-item', function(e) {
      var itemId = $(e).attr('data-id');
      var item = items.get(itemId);
      return {
        title: item.object + ' ' + item.subject,
        content: item.content
      }
   }, {
      cache: false
   });
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/3ynhek29/ ]

Comment: Hey that's great! :-) This has gotten me a big step further, thank you!